# Renaming .csv files during R import

Tags: r

I am not certain how to proceed with the following.  I have 179 .csv files that I want to import into R as dataframes.  The files are named xxx_####-####_xxx where x represents different letters and # represents different numbers.  Issues arise when I want to perform operations on the files since R recognizes ####-#### as an equation. Ideally, I would like to remove ####- from the file names.

To import many .csv files, I usually use the following script:

```
path <- paste0(getwd(), "/")
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv")
for(file in files)
{
  perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")
  assign( gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
          read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

This is an example of my filenames: BEMI-Mod1_1969-2015_Details_Plant_4_2015.csv.  I am having issues with the 1969-2015 part of the filename.  The script above allows me to import all the files into R as their file name.  Then when I want to manipulate the file I get the following error:

```
> BEMI-Mod1_1969-2015_Details_Plant_4_2015
Error: unexpected input in "BEMI-Mod1_1969-2015_"
```

Comment: Post example of you file name

Comment: Special characters in a file name normally aren't a problem when using `read.csv`.  Can you show us code where your file names are causing a problem?

Comment: you cannot have `-` in object names. Maybe use `gsub` to replace `-` with another character

Comment: I added a file name example with the error.